# Un able to click on a button inside a <strong> tag even after providing it's XPATH

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am attempting to find a robust xpath to click a button in the screenshot below

I want to click on the "eStatus" button

[image: I want to click on the "eStatus" button]

The HTML of the element is made up on the following

[image: The HTML of the element is made up on the following]

I have attempted to locate the button using the following xpath but it is not working.

```
login_Check=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[1]/ul/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/li/strong/em').click()
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to locate the element using xpath:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@id='mn1'][strong/em[text()='eStatus']]")
```

Since, the button is inside frame element, use below code to switch to the frame before accessing the button using above xpath:

```
frame_element = driver.find_element_by_name("IDXHeader")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_element)
```

Once you're done accessing element inside frame, make sure you siwtch back to default content using below code:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

So, your code should be as below:

```
frame_element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "IDXHeader")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_element)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@id='mn1'][strong/em[text()='eStatus']]").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

You could also use below code to locate button:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[strong/em[text()='eStatus']]")
```

Comment: it is giving this error message:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='mn1'][strong/em[text()='eStatus']]")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath

Comment: Check the edited answer. It should work unless your button is inside an iframe element.

Comment: it is still giving the error message: Unable to find element with xpath == //li[@id='mn1'][strong/em[text()='eStatus']]. I searched for iframe in the html while inspecting and didn't find it. but the button is inside: <frame marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" border="1" name="IDXHeader" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" src="MenuBar.action">

Comment: Edited the answer to switch to frame before accessing the button. Try this updated answer.

Comment: If you still are not able to access the button , try ```driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[strong/em[text()='eStatus']]") ``` to locate.

Comment: I am getting the error message: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'

Comment: Edited the answer. I hope it works. If it doesn't work, try with one more xpath I have provided at the end.

Comment: I have replaced `driver. find_element_by_name' with 'driver.find_element(By.NAME, "IDXHeader")'. Please check and try with 2nd xpath provided.

Comment: I tried it and the code executes successfully without any error message but it is still not clicking on the "eStatus" button.

Comment: Tried with 1st or 2nd xpath?

Comment: with the 2nd xpath. I used this code: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[strong/em[text()='eStatus']]")

Comment: Try ```driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@id='mn1'][strong/em[text()='eStatus']]").click()```

Comment: I tried the 1st xpath just now i.e.: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@id='mn1'][strong/em[text()='eStatus']]").click()
 and it worked. Thank you so so much sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Relative XPath expression: `//strong//em[text()='eStatus']`

```
login_Check = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//strong//em[text()="eStatus"]')
login_Check.click()
```

**UPDATE:** Try by inducing waits as below:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//strong//em[text()='eStatus']"))).click()
```

Import statements required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

**How to check if XPath expression locates the desired element:**

On your applicaiton, press <kbd>F12</kbd> --> <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> --> Paste the XPath expression (In this case try `//strong//em[text()='eStatus']` or this `//li[@id='mn1'][strong/em[text()='eStatus']]`)

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more.
I have typed it like this: 
login_Check = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//strong//em[text()='eStatus']').click()
and it is showing the error:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

Comment: Check the answer for updated code, try that and let me know the status.

Comment: this is the error message:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with xpath == //strong//em[text()="eStatus"]

Comment: Try the code in the updated answer. See if it locates element after inducing `wait`. Let me know the status. Also, check if there is an `iframe` within which this element is located?

Comment: the error message is as below and there is no 'iframe':  
File "c:\Users\dkhare\Desktop\Python_project\envision_bot\envision_login.py", line 21, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//strong//em[text()='eStatus']"))).click()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dkhare\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Check the updated answer, how to inspect and locate the desired element. Also, give the below code a try `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='mn1'][strong/em[text()='eStatus']]"))).click()`.

Comment: So, this: //strong//em[text()='eStatus'] is locating the desired element and when I used the code: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='mn1'][strong/em[text()='eStatus']]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='mn1'][strong/em[text()='eStatus']]"))).click()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dkhare\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Can you share the URL of the application if its not a sensitive info?

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot share the URL